# Can't figure out how to add current date to comment

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having problems with my sql code, i'm trying to implement a current date to my comment but i can't figure out how + i'm having syntax errors and i don't know what to do anymore. Can someone help me with the date adding to comment?

```
UPDATE Osalus_projektis AS op
SET op.töötasu = op.töötasu + 100,
op.comment = CONCAT(NOW()'tõusis palk 100 eurot')
FROM Osalus_projektis
INNER JOIN Osaluse_liik AS ol
ON ol.osaluse_liik = op.osaluse_liik
WHERE ol.nimetus = 'nõustaja';
```

Comment: You might want to cast to string before concatenating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access uses `&` for string concatenation.  And it doesn't support a `FROM` clause.  This may do what you want:

```
UPDATE Osalus_projektis AS op INNER JOIN
       Osaluse_liik AS ol
       ON ol.osaluse_liik = op.osaluse_liik
    SET op.töötasu = op.töötasu + 100,
        op.comment = NOW() & 'tõusis palk 100 eurot'
    WHERE ol.nimetus = 'nõustaja';
```

If there is a problem with the `JOIN` -- which happens a lot in MS Access -- then you can use an `EXISTS` clause as well.